# Why do migrated questions earn the poster -2 rep

Tags: support, reputation, migration

I was looking at my reputation history and noticed this:

[image]

It seems a bit unfair to lose rep for a migrated question. Now, I can understand this if you were to get, say, 10 migrated posts in a two week period (or something). But a lot of times you just don't realize it would be better on another site.

Comment: Well, you probably edited it here, and gained 2 rep through that edit. Since the question was migrated, you get the rep deducted. But, hey, you should get the rep on the target site.

Comment: You get rep for editing?

Comment: Up to a certain limit, yes. You get 2 rep for having a suggested edit approved. But you can only earn up to 1000 rep this way IIRC (I'm probably not remembering correctly, or maybe I am http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/).

Comment: Oh, you mean editing someone ELSE'S post... This was my post.

Comment: If you accepted an answer that also earns you 2 reputation. (and when it gets migrated you lose 2)

Comment: The reputation on accepted answers isn't lost -- it just moved to a different site. Register an account there, and you'll probably have 103 reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question to which you had accepted an answer, was migrated.

Since migration deletes posts on the source site, the 2 rep gained from accepting was removed as well